# How to get the last day of the current month in DataStage?

Tags: date, transformer-model, datastage

I have explored all the functions avialable in the trasformer, but could not found the exact function to get the last day of current month by passing date in same default format i.e. yyyy-mm-dd.Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Hello. to get the last day of a month you have to use the function DaysInMonth. here an example: Date = inputlink.dateVar
Year = YearFromDate(Date)
Month = MonthFromDate(Date) 
Day =   DaysInMonth(Date)
EndOfMonth = DateFromComponents(Year,Month,Day)

Comment: Did the input helped you to solve this problem?

Comment: But DaysInMonth() is not avialable in 8.1 version,I'm using DataStage 8.1 version. @funk

Comment: Hello. This should work: Field("31|28|31|30|31|30|31|31|30|31|30|31", "|", MonthFromDate(InLink.dateVar))

Comment: Hmm.. there is sth. missing in the code => handle the leap year (February: 28 or 29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field("31|28|31|30|31|30|31|31|30|31|30|31", "|", MonthFromDate(InLink.dateVar))

Answer (score 0):

It is more precise to establish the first day of next month then use DateFromDaysSince function to establish the day before. I created an integer(6) stage variable which contained century and month+1 from source link e.g. 201410

DateFromDaysSince(-1, StringToDate(svIHBKPR, "%yyyy%mm") : "%yyyy-%mm-%dd")

Answer (score 0):

There is a transformer function called DaysInMonth. 
Example: DaysInMonth(“2017-01-23”)= 31